# Autolayout Constraints for an autosizing Parent UIView with ' N ' number of labels, as subviews , in swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

The Parent view is an simple UIView. The parent view contains 'n' number of labels . In my case, the parent view's width should be the width of the label with the maximum width, and not more than that. How to create auto layout constraints for this case?

NOTE : All the Labels are only single Line Labels and doesnot have multiple lines.

Comment: Do you want to create all the labels programatically? When you say 'n' number of labels, if all those labels won't fit in the view, do you need a scroll?

Comment: Either use a `StackView`, or set all the labels to `Equal Width`.

Comment: @Satyam, No I don't need a scroll. I mentioned 'n' in a generalised way. Assume it as 4

Comment: make all labels equal width with appropriate content compression resistance. then set leading and trailing, top and bottom constraints(as a list) and set parent views leading top and height constraints. (but not width)

Comment: It appears you wish to use constraints. (You haven't stated if you are using IB and/or Storyboards, but it should matter as long as you make the constraints `IBOutlets`. You will **need** to do *at least* this many calculations in code. (1) The screen width. (2) What is the value of "N"? (3) What is the "maximum width of the label you are talking about in your question. Basically, **after** setting your initial constraint - and if solely using code, then declaring the maximum width of... some label - you can **calculate** what you need and alter the constants as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use UIStakView and put all labels in this stack view. Then add constraints to this stack view.

Comment: V.Nair , Is there any way without using stack views, Since stack views can't be used in iOS 8.0 devices

Comment: Hard to downvote this answer.... you need to make this restriction i your question!